# Spacing between elements

Tags: html, css

Here is the fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qJTDK/)

Why there is space between textarea and button and how to remove it?

I have tried setting `margin` and `padding` to `0` but it didn't help.

Comment: You should include the relevant code in the question itself. Jsfiddle is a useful thing to add, not a substitute for including code.

Comment: What spacing are you referring to, and on which browser(s)?

Comment: I referred the space between elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of the `line-height` for `.wrapper` class. Add the following style in your css.

```
.wrapper{line-height:0px}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qJTDK/3/)

**EDIT:**

The above solution is working fine in Chrome and Firefox. In IE it will truncate all the `line-height` for child elements. So you have to mentioned explicitly `line-height` for inner elements like below.

```
 textarea,
 submit_raw_wrapper,
 button {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 line-height:16px;
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qJTDK/5/)

Comment: Thanks:) I don't know how I missed it..:)

Comment: This has no effect when I test on Firefox and Chrome. On IE 11, it shrinks the button to a thin horizontal line.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela thanks for pointing out on IE issue. I have updated my answer. please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

just adjust the floating:

eg.

```
textarea,
submit_raw_wrapper,
button {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textarea,
submit_raw_wrapper,
button {
margin:0;padding:0;float:left;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qJTDK/2/)